# Generate WSDL specific version

Tags: soap-api, wsdl, versioning

Is it possible to specify SOAP version for I want to get WSDL file generated ?
As I saw on  Setup->Develop->API there is possible to download metadata only for last one SF version under which I am using setup. For me that was 29.0.

I would like to say, create partner WSDL for SOAP v16 API per instance. How to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, you can only download the WSDL for the latest API version.